# How to preserve previous array when using splice method

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, splice

I want to preserve my previous array on calling splice method on that array

```
lets we have an array content

let content = ['post', 'tweet', 'video', 'talk']
let removed = content.splice(2)

removed:["video", "talk"]
content: ["post", "tweet"]
```

How can I preserve my content array when using splice?

Comment: slice, don't splice :)

Answer (score 3):

The key here is to use `slice` rather than `splice`, as the original array will be retained.

```js
let content = ['post', 'tweet', 'video', 'talk'];
let removed = content.slice(2);

console.log(content);
console.log(removed);
```

Use [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use splice method try this

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content)).splice(2);
```

```js
let content = ['post', 'tweet', 'video', 'talk'];
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content)).splice(2));
console.log(content);
```